# SAT arithmetic and pre-calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus

1.for the annual school fundraiser, santiago has p pledges each for c cents per lap that he jogs. If his school track has 4 laps per mile and santiago raises a total of d dollars, how many miles did he jog in terms of p,c, and d?

1) 25d/pc
2)4pc/d
3)100d/pc
4)4pcd
5)25pcd

For #1, I can plug numbers for the problem but I want to know the algebraic method.

1. The minute hand of a clock has a length of l from its point of rotation to the point at the end of the arrow. What is the total distance traveled by the point at the end of the arrow in m minutes?
2. In the Subtraction problem of a three-digit number from a four digit number: A4B7-A4B=5CA7 , A, B, and C represent 3 different digits. What digit does C represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pledge problem goes like this: If he raised $d$ dollars, he raised $100d$ cents. But each mile he runs he raises $4pc$ cents. So if $m$ is the number of miles he ran, he raised a total of $4pcm$ cents. Since the *number of cents raised must be the same regardless of how we derive it*, we get $4pcm = 100d$. (This is the core of translating any word problem into an equation: Find *some quantity* $-$ in this case the number of cents raised $-$ that can, from the given explanation, be expressed in two ways. Those two ways must be equal, and there you have your equation.) The problem asks you to express $m$, which is easy to do from here.

The clock one is the most straight-forward of these: In one minute the tip of the minute hand moves $1/60$ of the entire circumference. The circumference is $2\pi l$, so that means one minute's travel is equal to $\pi l / 30$. In $m$ minutes it has travelled $m\pi l/30$.

The subtraction problem can be done like this: Look at the last digit. It says that $7-B = 7$. Thus we must have $B = 0$. In that case, the tens digit says $0 - 4 = A$, which needs borrowing / regrouping into $10 - 4 = A$, so $A = 6$. We now have $6407 - 640 = 5C67$. Now can you figure out what $C$ is?